# Switch to stop battery from discharging step up

Tags: voltage, power, batteries, charge

I have a problem with this circuit.

The circuit works fine with the LDO, step up and battery management.

However, when the step up still remains on when the SHDN is set to zero.

Effectively, I would need to have a switch just before the step up to ensure that the battery does not discharge when the circuit is not in use.

What ways can I make a switch that does not involve a physical button or a physical switch? A relay is too big for the circuit. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: The LT3467 is still technically on but it should only take 1uA when it's in shutdown. That shouldn't cause problems with battery discharge.

Comment: When it's active low and circuit is not used it discharges around 50mA.

When idle high it does not discharge.

Comment: You could use a MOSFET as an electronic switch. That said, when you say the step-up remains on, is the voltage output something greater than 0V?

Comment: What I mean by that is that the mosfet becomes a passive component meaning it is outputing the battery voltage to the output. I want the level of SHDN to go to high when not used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a solid state switch?

A P-Channel MOSFET would be a good suitable choice, provided current only.flows one direction through the FET (battery only discharges).

The P-Channel MOSFET is ideal because it's is effectively a normally closed switch, when a voltage is applied to the gate then it will switch prevent battery discharge. Have a look with Google and see if this  work for your design.

Comment: Thank you yes I will have a look

Comment: Would you mind sketching how you would add it to the circuit? Thanks